# How to modify geth node configuration after launch

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to modify geth configuration when the node is running?
For instance, open a port, add more parameter flag to control geth node functions.

I think maybe there are two ways:
One is stop the node and re-launch with new parameters. but not sure it's feasible.
the other one is use command api, if it permits, which command can be used to re-configure?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to change:

There is a console to which you can 'geth attach' with some API

For most of the options you will need to restart, but instead of changing the command line options each time, i would suggest using toml configuration file and modify the options inside the file

Comment: Thanks.what's toml configuration file,is there some tool? Need I stop the node when modify the toml configuration file? Besides, can I also modify the parameter set in genesis.json after node launch.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options in short create one with dumpconfig and load it later with --config <file>

Comment: when modify configuration, need the node stop and then restart with new one,is it correct?

Comment: yes, the config is read on startup (look at it as predefined command line options), so you need to restart